# Jquery different ways of selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between below 3 jquery statements ?

```
$("div")

$("<div>")

$("<div/>")
```

Comment: First one selects `div` elements from _DOM_, other two creates new `div` element

Comment: to add to @Tushar 's comment. Last two are actually the same, both are faulty since jQuery requires a complete html element to add, so jQuery completes the html with the missing tag.

Comment: ok.thanks a lot for quick reply. 2nd and 3rd one both created div elements with any differences?

Comment: @Parashuram They are incomplete, so jQuery automaticaly fills in the missing `</div>` for the first one, and `<div>` for the second one. Resulting in `<div></div>` for both.